# Applying Sequence in Cron4J

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, sequence

I am using cron4j to schedule tasks to run every 30 minutes. However, I would like not to run a 2nd instance of the task execution if the previous instance of the same task is still being executed. 
I know that there are methods like isLive() and join() in Executor, but not sure the appropriate method of using them to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to achieve sequential processing. If that's the case, my suggestion is to use queue as the 'pipe' between 2 cron4j tasks, the rask who produces process parameters, and the task that processes the parameters.

cron4j (task1, 30 minutes interval) that prepares parameters, put into the -----> queue <----- cron4j (task2, perhaps 10 minutes interval) reads parameters from this, and process accordingly.

In cron4j's task 2, after processing the parameter from the queue, it can check again the queue's content before finishing, and continue processing if there's something new in the queue.

With this approach, things are processed sequentially, and the 2 tasks are loosely coupled, because they interface with the queue object.

You could use java.util.Queue for the queue.

Comment: sorry to respond you late on this. I missed any possible notification of your response.

Comment: Infact, I have only process but that is scheduled to run every 30 minutes. I just want to control the over run of a 2nd instance of the same process when the first one is running. Let's assume, the job is to copy data from table A to table B every 30 minutes. The scheduled process started at 8:00 AM. It took longer than 30 minutes, but at 8:30 AM, the schedular would start the same process. How to control this over-run actually?

Comment: @Bokhari: as i stated in my answer, my suggestion is that your scheduler's process is not about copying file, but create a task-object, and add the task-object to a queue, let's call it a task-queue. And then there is another scheduler, process is to see whether there are new tasks in the task-queue, get the task, remove it from the queue, and process the task, which is copying file in your case. Even if you havent finished copying the file and new tasks are being added, the second scheduler that is still processing will have to wait until it finishes before fetching a new task from the queue.